# Protractor - clicking and sendKeys not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am writing a Protractor test, and as part of the test I wish to clear the content of a particular field (on a textarea), and then use the sendKeys method to write some content onto that textarea.

Here's the code from my test:

```
var commentField = element(by.css('input[ng-model="comment"]'));
console.log(commentField);
commentField.clear();
commentField.sendKeys('Here is a comment');
```

The console log confirms that I am indeed finding a control, but as soon as it hits the clear() method the test just hangs.

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? Also, what protractor version are u using, is it reproducible in both chrome and firefox? Thanks.

Comment: Hi alecse - Unfortunately I am under restrictions from management in terms of what I can post to stackoverflow... I think I have found the problem though - it looks like browser synchronisation...

Comment: If you remove the sendKeys line does it clear the text field ok? If you are ignoring synchronization, maybe you need some kind of wait between clearing the field and adding new text.

Comment: Now that I am ignoring syncrhonisation it all works fine.,..

Answer (score 4):

We use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` if the page is not angular page. Because the protractor is coded for angular. But, I see ng selector:

```
var commentField = element(by.css('input[ng-model="comment"]'));
```

This error may be due to other things:

1. Browser driver (Try to use chromedriver)
2. Lack of testability plugin. Please visit this link for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-testability-plugin

Make sure you use jasmine2 framework, and to update webdriver, type to command line this: `webdriver-manager update`

Answer (score 3):

Just to let people know - I needed to use

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

after the call to move to the target page, but before attempting to click, clear or edit anything.

Happy days!

Answer (score 0):

There was(is) a problem with `.clear()` where if you didn't fulfill the promise, the `sendKeys()` method wouldn't work.

Try using `async/await` or fulfill the promise.

```
element.clear().then(() => {
    element.sendKeys('text to send')
})
```